# Show that the proposition is a tautology using logical equivalences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

$$ (p \vee q ) \wedge (\lnot p \vee r) \to
q \vee r$$

So far what I have is:

$$\lnot((p \vee q) \wedge (\lnot p \vee r)) \vee (q \vee r)$$

$$(\lnot(p \vee q) \vee \lnot(\lnot p \vee r)) \vee (q \vee r)$$

$$((\lnot p \wedge \lnot q) \vee (p \wedge \lnot r)) \vee (q \vee r)$$

This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: What are your axioms?

Comment: p,q,r have no statements linked with them. This problem is just testing my knowledge on logical equivalences. In this problem the only equivalence I have applied is deMorgan's law. After that Im not sure what other equivalence to use.

Comment: Logical equivalences still have axioms.  De Morgan's law is one.  Another might be $\lnot(p\land\lnot p)$.

Comment: Third line is mistake.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed it should be (p AND not r) not (p OR not r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First apply conditional equivalence then apply de morgan's law twice, this is correct so far, after that, to prove this with [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence), all we need is keep using Associative law, Commutative law, Distributive law, Negation law, Identity law, and in the end we need to apply Domination law twice:

\begin{align}
&(p \vee q ) \wedge (\lnot p \vee r) \to q \vee r\\
\equiv&\lnot((p \vee q) \wedge (\lnot p \vee r)) \vee (q \vee r)\tag*{Conditional Equivalence}\\
\equiv&((\lnot p \wedge \lnot q) \vee (p \wedge \lnot r)) \vee (q \vee r)\tag*{De Morgan's laws$\times 2$}\\
\equiv&(\lnot p \wedge \lnot q) \vee ((p \wedge \lnot r) \vee (q \vee r))\tag*{Associative law}\\
\equiv&(\lnot p \wedge \lnot q) \vee ((p \wedge \lnot r) \vee (r \vee q))\tag*{Commutative law}\\
\equiv&(\lnot p \wedge \lnot q) \vee (((p \wedge \lnot r) \vee r) \vee q)\tag*{Associative law}\\
\equiv&(\lnot p \wedge \lnot q) \vee (q\vee((p \wedge \lnot r) \vee r))\tag*{Commutative law}\\
\equiv&((\lnot p \wedge \lnot q) \vee q)\vee((p \wedge \lnot r) \vee r))\tag*{Associative law}\\
\equiv&((\lnot p\vee q) \wedge (\lnot q\vee q))\vee((p\vee r) \wedge (\lnot r\vee r))\tag*{Distributive law}\\
\equiv&((\lnot p\vee q) \wedge \top)\vee((p\vee r) \wedge \top)\tag*{Negation law}\\
\equiv&(\lnot p\vee q)\vee(p\vee r)\tag*{Identity law}\\
\equiv&(q\vee\lnot p)\vee(p\vee r)\tag*{Commutative law}\\
\equiv&((q\vee\lnot p)\vee p)\vee r\tag*{Associative law}\\
\equiv&(q\vee(\lnot p\vee p))\vee r\tag*{Associative law}\\
\equiv&(q\vee\top)\vee r\tag*{Negation law}\\
\equiv&\top\tag*{Domination law$\times2$}\\
\end{align}

Hence we proved it's a tautology.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easier to show that an expression is a contradiction (always false).

Using another more convenient way to write logical expressions you have

- $E = ((p+q)(p'+r))' + q+r$

Now using DeMorgan rules

$$E' = (p+q)(p'+r)q'r' \stackrel{xx'=0}{=}(0+pr+qp'+qr)q'r' = 0+0+0+0 = 0$$

So, $E'$ is a contradiction, hence $E$ is a tautology.